# Extract 9 Digit String With Hyphen As Second Character

Tags: regex

I have a string such as "subject:  Re: 'HC=002-750-482' Claim Number: 1234567, Serv Ref: 2-1410473, Prov ID: 12345

I want to extract the Serv Ref. This will always be 9 characters and have a hyphen after the first numeric value.

I am using

```
"(?<![\d-])\d{9}(?!\d)"
```

Comment: Why are you using `"(?<![\d-])\d{9}(?!\d)"`? There are no 9 consecutive digits there. If you have a hyphen, match it, `\b\d-\d{7}\b` (as I see, there are 8 digits all in all, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74JkrC/1))

Comment: Thanks, apologies my understanding was I was searching a 9 character string. If you want to submit the entire query I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substring starts with a digit, then contains a hyphen, and then *seven* digits. All in all, there are eight digits and a hyphen.

All you need here is

```js
\b\d-\d{7}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74JkrC/1)

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d` - a digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{7}` - seven digits
- `\b` - word boundary.